# confusion regarding embedded BSONDocument in reactiveMongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I have stored following data in MongoDB

```
db.users.insert({id: 1,user: {firstname:"John",lastname:"Cena",email:["jc@wwe.com","jc1@wwe.com"],password:"YouCantSeeMe",address:{street:"34 some street", country:"USA"}}})
```

I queried as follows expecting that the first query will not work but the second will. To my surprise, it was the other way round.

This query worked

```
val query1 = BSONDocument("user.firstname"->user.firstName)
```

This didn't

```
val query2 = BSONDocument("user"-> BSONDocument("firstname"->user.firstName))
```

I observed that query1 creates following structure (by running mongodb in verbose mode, mongodb -v)
`{ user.firstname: "John" }`

But query2 creates following structure
`{ user: { firstname: "John" } }`

Aren't these two the same (firstname is inside user)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not the same.

First query works because you are  comparing the fields of embedded document using dot notation.

Second query fails because you are comparing document as a whole against a embedded document.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation